# Soapui property transfer to request header

Tags: web-services, xpath, soapui

I want to set the value of token in this soap ws header

```
<soapenv:Enveloppe ...
<soapenv:Header>
    <web:token>123456 </web:token>
```

FROM step named test get idSession in response

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
             <ns1:authentification xmlns:ns1="http://ws.demowebservices.com/">
                <bloc1>
                    <bloc2>
                          <idSession>e1c64cd9-b933-4f56-ae1f-0f7d7f23942b</idSession>
                    </bloc2>
```

I tried to put in-between web:token tag

```
   ${test#Response#//ns1:authentification/bloc1/bloc2/idSession}
```

but it does not work

What should I put instead ?

Comment: Have you tried documentation? http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html#1-Custom-HTTP-Headers

Comment: What SiKing suggested should help you. You may also take a look at this along with it http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/tips---tricks.html#5-Change-a-request-XML-from-groovy

Comment: Why would I need custom header or use groovy ? Why can I set request header with property transfer like I  can do with request body ? I'm very beginner I want as simple solution as possible : so am I really obliged to give up property transfer ?

Comment: @user310291 what do you trying to do exactly? Put a value in `<web:token>` from another `SOAP` request or reponse?

Comment: @albciff yes exactly. I can do it when it's in request body, I don't understand why the same syntax does not work in reqjest header.

Comment: @user310291 take a look at my answer, I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve, I hope that you'll find it useful `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve, however If you have a `SOAP Test step` called `Test Request` and you want to use the value of the `<soapenv:Header><web:token></soapenv:Header>` of this request in another `SOAP Test step` you can refer this value in the second `SOAP Test step` request using the follow syntax:

```
<soapenv:Enveloppe ...
<soapenv:Header>
    <web:token>${Test Request#Request#//soapenv:Header/web:token}</web:token>
```

The syntax `${Test Request#Request#//soapenv:Header/web:token}` has three parts, the name of the test step, followed by the property (could be `#Request` or `#Response`), and finally the `xpath` to get the value `//soapenv:Header/web:token`.

**UPDATED:**

As you said you've two `SOAP Test Request`, the first one is called `test` an has the follow `response`:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:authentification xmlns:ns1="http://ws.demowebservices.com/">
         <bloc1>
            <bloc2>
               <idSession>e1c64cd9-b933-4f56-ae1f-0f7d7f23942b</idSession>
            </bloc2>
         </bloc1>
      </ns1:authentification>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The second is named for example `test 2` (don't care because the second name not affect your purpose) and has the follow `request`:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <web:token>${test#Response#//ns1:authentification/bloc1/bloc2/idSession}</web:token>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With `${test#Response#//ns1:authentification/bloc1/bloc2/idSession}` you're referencing the `idSession` value of the `test` response correctly. Take a look on the `http log` tab when you send your `test 2` as shown in the follow image:

[image]

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I need, I'm waiting after the server's guy to be able to test it :)

Comment: @user310291 ok perfect `:)`, so finally works? nice to help you!

Comment: I have error : can you look at my updated post thanks :)

Comment: @user310291 I think that you're using the correct expression, take a look on my updated answer, hope this helps `:)`

Comment: you saved my day, in fact my week ! I looked at debug web:idSession was empty then I realized I had a space between step name and #response